Issue with Android Studio: "Process is still running" on Ubuntu
I am a new Ubuntu user, and I am experiencing an issue with Android Studio after restarting my PC. Whenever I try to open Android Studio, I receive the following error:

Process "/app/extra/android-studio/bin/studio" (2) is still running.  
If the process is an instance of the IDE, please collect the logs and contact support.  
If it isn't, please delete the stale "/home/hisham/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/config/Google/AndroidStudio2024.2/.lock" file and restart the IDE.  

Even after following the advice to delete the .lock file, the problem persists. I have tried using htop to search for the process but could not find any running instances of Android Studio. To resolve the issue temporarily, I have to reinstall Android Studio, which is tedious and time-consuming.
I am looking for a more permanent solution to this problem or any insights into why this error keeps happening.
What I Tried:
I checked running processes using htop to see if any instance of Android Studio was still active.
Expected: I expected to find a running process related to Android Studio that I could terminate to resolve the issue.
Result: No related process was found in htop.
I deleted the .lock file located at /home/hisham/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/config/Google/AndroidStudio2024.2/.lock as suggested in the error message.
Expected: Deleting the .lock file would allow Android Studio to start normally.
Result: While this temporarily resolves the issue, the problem reoccurs every time I restart my PC.
I reinstalled Android Studio as a last resort.
Expected: Reinstalling would completely resolve the issue and prevent it from happening again.
Result: Reinstallation works temporarily, but the issue comes back after restarting the PC.

Have you tried manually closing the IDE before restarting the PC?

I have the same problem :/
